# NodeJS/Angular Can't Delete an Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to remove an object on a MongoDB database/NodeJS. It is working on a rest client but with a button to delete the item on Angular it doesn't work. Each time I test it out on REST Client it works fine, but with Angular it doesn't work.

How would I fix it to make it work? Below is my code:

```
//still need to resolve the delete function
  //still need to resolve the delete function
     $scope.remove = function(item) {  
         itemid = $scope.item.id; 

         console.log(item.id);

         $http({ url: "http://localhost:3000/api/book", 
                 method: "DELETE",
                 data: "id="+item.id, 
                 headers: {"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

               }).then(function(res) {
                 console.log(res.data);
                 console.log("good");
               }, function(error) {
                 console.log(error);
                 console.log("bad");
               });
       }
```

My Node/Express code

```
//Delete an existing book
app.delete("/api/book", function(req, res){

 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "DELETE");

  Book.findOneAndRemove({ id: req.params.id}, function(err, result){
    res.json({
    message: "Successfully deleted the book",
    book: result
  });
  });
 });
```

Comment: I would suspect it's `_id` and not `id` that you are trying to remove. Also a bit redundant to send both the `isbn` and the `ObjectId` value in the request, so just make it one of them instead.

Answer (score 1):

`params` object is inside `body`, so you have to change your endpoint to:

```
app.delete("/api/book/:isbn", function(req, res){
 console.log('Client Reached the endpoint.');
 Book.findOneAndRemove({ id: req.body.params._id}, function(err, result){
     res.json({
       message: "Successfully deleted the book",
       book: result
     });
  });
 });
```

---

### Recommendations

Since you're not using `isbn`, you should change your endpoint to:

```
app.delete( "/api/book/:id", function ( req, res ) {
    Book.findOneAndRemove( { id: req.params.id }, function ( err, result ) {
        res.json( {
            message: "Successfully deleted the book",
            book: result
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Your angular function then will be:

```
//Updated
$scope.remove = function () {

    $http( {
        method: 'DELETE',
        url: '/api/book/' + item.id //Verify if item.id has a value...
    } ).then(
        function ( response ) {
            console.log( 'Sucess', response );
        },
        function ( response ) {
            console.log( 'Fail', response )
        }
    );

};
```

Remember the following

> params: `"/api/route/:param"` 
>  call: `req.params.param`
>
> query strings(e.g. `/api/route/1?somequery=something`):
>   `"/api/route/:param"` 
>  call:  `req.query.somequery`
>
> data (e.g. `{id: 1, name: 'x'}`): `"/api/route/:param"` 
>  call:
>   `req.body.id`, `req.body.name`

Comment: This didn't work, but I went ahead and modified my code which shows an error of DELETE XHR.

Comment: Hmmm, use [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) to test the endpoint `http://localhost:3000/api/book/` see if it's server side code the problem, or if it's client side, you said server side was working right?, how do you know?

Comment: I tested with REST Client. It's good, so my guess is the problem is on the client side. I do appreciate your help though. :)

Comment: Try the recommended code, I'll make an update, so wait and check out

Comment: Check out @JeffreyTeruel, not sure if it's so necessary to name the param `id`

Comment: Just tried it out, I get a fail message: Fail Object { data: null, status: 0, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" } controller.js:95:13. Good news is there's no more XHR error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95986/discussion-between-feniixx-and-jeffrey-teruel).

Answer (score 0):

You can use service in frontend side

```
angular.module('users').factory('MyService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource(':url/:id1/:id2', {},
        {
            'delete': { method: 'DELETE' }
        });
},
]);
```

and use this service in your function

```
$scope.remove = function() {  
   MyService.get({url: 'book', id1: item.id
                }).$promise.then(function(result) {
                   console.log(""Success);
                }).catch(function(error){
                   console.log("error");
                });
}
```

Make base url as localhost:3000/api in service and defned this service in controller.